Detect Global Phase
Generally, in the study of quantum mechanics, the global phase of a system is ignored because it does not change the probability of the results occurring, nor which results can occur. I would like to know if this is a general rule or if there are cases where the global phase cannot be ignored.
I think, for example, if the probability of finding a particle in space at a given moment is the cosine squared of the position, then a global phase would make a difference since at the same moment the probability of finding the particle in the same position would depend on the global phase.
I just don't know if there are cases like this in quantum mechanics.
And if in general it does not change anything, why we still care about writing it?

In your example, you're assuming a wavefunction of the form
$$\psi(x) = e^{i\theta}\cos(kx), $$
then the probability density is simply
$$P(x) = |\psi(x)|^2=\psi\psi^* = |e^{i\theta}|\cos^2(kx)=\cos^2(kx). $$
The global phase of a state $e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ is not relevant since all observables are ultimately quantities of the form $\langle \psi|O|\psi \rangle$, and therefore the $e^{i\theta}$ term gets cancelled with its complex conjugate. Phases are relevant when considering a superposition of states, such as
$$e^{i\alpha}|\psi_1\rangle + \ e^{i\beta}|\psi_2\rangle,$$
then the relative phase $\delta=\beta-\alpha$ has a physical effect in observable quantities. For example, consider the probability density of the state above, assuming the vectors are not orthogonal. Then
$$|e^{i\alpha}(|\psi_1\rangle + |\psi_2\rangle e^{i\delta})|^2 = 2 \ + 2\cos(\delta). $$
The phase difference produces an interference pattern conceptually identical to that of electromagnetic waves.

Today earlier I thought about this case you mentioned, but I found the result strange because if the phase difference is pi, the probability of finding the particle anywhere would be zero.

That's only the case when $|\psi_1\rangle=|\psi_2\rangle$. If that's your condition, a $\pi$ phase difference implies that the total state is $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle + e^{i\pi}|\psi_1\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle-|\psi_1\rangle=0$. This state is just the null state.
